# How to disable SVG scroll?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to disable the scrolling of the svg. I tried to put the property overflow to hidden or visible but the svg still to scroll.
I created the jsfiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/pct8rL03/1/

```css
.svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wave-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M0,95 C90,130 250,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#e0efe3;"></path>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="wave-container">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
                    <path d="M0,95 C90,130 250,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#e0efe3;"></path>
                </svg>                
            </div>  

body{
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px px;
}
.svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wave-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This maybe the right answer - but it will be much better if you explain your - what have you change and why...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your `wave-container` css and you don't need to give a position and display css for your `svg`. The css for your `wave-container` should be enough. Hope this helps

```css
.wave-container {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave-container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <path d="M0,95 C90,130 250,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#e0efe3;"></path>
      </svg>      
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do here. Your SVG is just to big and add to much blank space at the bottom. To fix it just update your SVG file.

**Not a good practice:**

You can use the property `overflow: hidden;` on your `.wave-container` but to make it work you have to set a `height` or `max-height` to it